# Flutter calling a method inside the build method

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a screen with two widgets, one has a button the other one has a bottom sheet function.
I want to invoke the bottom sheet function from the other widget the problem is that my bottom sheet function needs context which makes it must be invoked inside the build function. I can invoke any function using a voidcallback on widget 1 which has the button and a constructor method on widget 2 but I need context to invoke this function. How is it possible to achieve that?
[image]

Comment: you need the context of the widget from where you are triggering this, pass that context in method parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just make your method accept a `BuildContext context` as parameter, then when you call it you can pass the context of the widget that makes the call.

Comment: How can I call a function inside the state from the statefulwidget? and what if it an asynchronous function?

Comment: why do you want to call it in `state`? why not call it in `initState()`?

Comment: I'm not trying to call it in the state that would be easy since it is already in the same scope. Why should I call it in initState()? initState() would run every time the program runs which is not the desirable outcome. My function exist in the state I want to call it from the constructor in the statefulwidget so I can call it from out side the widget.

Comment: i can't tell what you really want without code but you can call methods in stateful widget inside by using `widget.methodName()`

Comment: Inside the state I can call methods inside statefulwidget using widget.methodName(). But I want the reverse I have my bottom sheet function inside the state because it has elements that needs setState() I can't place it anywhere else. I need to invoke that function from the constructor so I can invoke it from outside the widget.

Comment: well for that you need a global state, and you have to use a state management technique to achieve that, take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tm-R7ymwhc&t=513s) to know what it's all about.

Comment: Why is it more beneficial to do this, instead of defining the method inside the build method?